# preg_match(): Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class with escaped \

Tags: php, json, regex, compiler-warnings

I am trying to run a regex on a JSON string to verify data is as expected before continuing with my script.

Here is an example of the JSON to run the regex on:

```
[{"id":"01001001","b":"1","c":"1","v":"1","t":"Some \"Text\""},{"id":"01001002","b":"1","c":"1","v":"2","t":"More Text"},{"id":"01001003","b":"1","c":"1","v":"3","t":"And Even More"}]
```

I have tested the following regex as working at [phpliveregex.com](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/kdm):

```
\[(\{"id":"[0-9]{8}","b":"[0-9]{1,2}","c":"[0-9]{1,2}","v":"[0-9]{1,3}","t":"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"\})(,\{"id":"[0-9]{8}","b":"[0-9]{1,2}","c":"[0-9]{1,2}","v":"[0-9]{1,3}","t":"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"\})*\]
```

Here is how I put it together in PHP:

```
$sv = '01001001';
$ev = '01001003';
$url = 'http://api.amasterdesigns.com/?sv='.$sv.'&ev='.$ev;
$JSON = file_get_contents($url);
//return JSON only if properly formatted
if(preg_match('/\[(\{"id":"[0-9]{8}","b":"[0-9]{1,2}","c":"[0-9]{1,2}","v":"[0-9]{1,3}","t":"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"\})(,\{"id":"[0-9]{8}","b":"[0-9]{1,2}","c":"[0-9]{1,2}","v":"[0-9]{1,3}","t":"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"\})*\]/',$JSON)){
    return json_decode($JSON);
} else {
    return;
}
```

The problem I am receiving is when I run this page I receive this error

> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for
>   character class at offset 202 in
>   path_to_file/my-file.php on line 1422

Line 1422 is line 6 of the above code snippet. I believe this is pointing to `[^"\\]` near the end of my regex, but I do have a terminating `]` following an escaped `\`.

You can see the errors using [PHP sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1ccc35d43a4e98903508852ab70021025f2f1301)

Comment: Why are you trying to parse JSON with a regexp instead of using `json_decode()`?

Comment: I want to ensure that the data is what I expect before it is decoded.

Comment: It will be much easier to decode the JSON and then validate the contents.

Comment: More particularly, I am using this code in a WordPress plugin and wanted to add another layer of validation before outputting errors on the public side in case there is a bad response from the API where the JSON is retrieved.

Comment: It would still be much easier to parse the JSON, check `json_last_error`, and then traverse the parsed object/array to validate the data than cramming it all into one regex.

Comment: Starting with the fact that the order of keys in a JSON object is immaterial, so expecting a certain order for validation makes your code extremely fragile.

Comment: @deceze I am the one also controlling the API, so I know how the data will be sent over, I am just adding a step to make sure that it was not changed along the way. Maybe a little overboard here, I am also validating the data after it is decoded in another place in the script.

Comment: Unless you're cobbling together the JSON by hand (don't do that), but you're actually using `json_encode`, you have very little guarantee what order the keys in that object will be output in. `{"foo": "bar", "baz": 42}` and `{"baz": 42, "foo": "bar"}` are absolutely equivalent as far as JSON is concerned, and you have virtually no guarantee how exactly the result of a `json_encode` will look; even less in other languages. That's why JSON validation through regex is extremely likely to fail soon for perfectly valid code.

Comment: @wiktor I reviewed the possible duplicate answer before posting my question. The answer did not clearly define what the problem was as the accepted answer to this question did.

Comment: Another link added to the close reason.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I did not see that question because I did not know that escaping the backslash was the problem. I assumed that I had already escaped the backslash correctly. At least now I know, so be it if it remains as a duplicate even though I think that the wording would make this unique and helpful to others in search of similar problem.

Comment: Yes, it will help. It will redirect to those posts. Barmar did not explain much anyway. The essence is: a regex engine expects a literal backslash as an escaping symbol. The rest of the explanation is available at [PHP string literals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) where we see that even in single-quoted PHP string literals, you need to use ``\\`` to define a literal backslash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part:

```
[^"\\]
```

needs to be:

```
[^"\\\\]
```

You need to double the backslashes again because they act as escapes in both string and regular expression syntax. `\\` turns into `\` when it gets sent to `preg_match`, and that's escaping the `]` instead of treating backslash as one of the characters in the character set.

Comment: Thank you. This worked after applying this fix to every \\

Answer (score 0):

The first check on `v` is missing an opening `[`:

```
"v":"0-9]{1,3}"  // should be:
"v":"[0-9]{1,3}"
```

Comment: I'm sorry some how I error in copying/pasting and formatting my code in my question. This beginning `[` is in place. Please see edit.

Comment: There is no *must* here. Closing bracket alone doesn't mean a special character in a regex.

Comment: @revo no, but if you're trying to match 1-3 characters in the range of 0-9, PECL will need one there to work as you want. Otherwise it would look for the literal string "0-9" followed by 1-3 "]" characters.

Comment: `PECL` or `PCRE`?

Comment: @revo got my acronyms mixed up. You're right, I meant PCRE. Sorry!

Comment: Yet provided error doesn't have anything to do with missing opening bracket.

Comment: Yes, that's why @Barmar's answer is the accepted one. I'm not deleting this answer, because it did lead to an edit in the original question. Even though this was not the answer to the original problem.

Comment: ... and I didn't try to make you do so.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Barmar's answer, or wrap your regex in a [nowdoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) format:

```
$re = <<< 'RE'
/\[(\{"id":"[0-9]{8}","b":"[0-9]{1,2}","c":"[0-9]{1,2}","v":"[0-9]{1,3}","t":"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"\})(,\{"id":"[0-9]{8}","b":"[0-9]{1,2}","c":"[0-9]{1,2}","v":"[0-9]{1,3}","t":"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"\})*\]/
RE;

if (preg_match($re, $JSON)) {
    print_r(json_decode($JSON));
}
```